# How to hide AWS S3 Bucket URL with custom CNAME

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cdn

I want to connect CDN to an AWS S3 Bucket, but the [AWS Document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html#VirtualHostingCustomURLs) indicates that the bucket name must be the same as the CNAME. Therefore, it is very easy to guess the real s3 bucket url by others.

For example,

```
- My domain: example.com  
- My S3 Bucket name: image.example.com  
- My CDN CNAME(image.example.com) will point to image.example.com.s3.amazonaws.com
```

After that, people can access the CDN URL -> http://image.example.com to obtain the resources from my S3 Bucket. However, under this restriction, people can guess my real S3 bucket url from the CNAME (CNAME + s3.amazonaws.com) easily.

So, my question is that how can I hide my real s3 bucket url? Because I don't want to expose my real S3 url to anyone for preventing any attacks.

Comment: What's the difference between people obtaining resources from image.example.com/resource and image.example.com.s3.amazonaws.com/resource? How is hiding the domain name going to help?

Comment: @kichik maybe because you don't want to expose your bucket's real name which **uniquely and exclusively aids you** to understand its purpose. That's why you must use meaningful names when you need to handle many buckets/resources_of_the_same_type

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure I understand what you are asking for or what you are trying to do [hiding your bucket does not really help anything], however I will attempt to answer your question regarding "hiding" your bucket name. Before I answer, I would like to ask these two questions:

- Why do you want to hide your S3 bucket url?
- What kind of attacks are you trying to prevent?

You are correct that the S3 bucket name **had** to be the same as your URL. This is **no longer** a requirement as you can mask the S3 bucket using [cloudfront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/). CloudFront as you know is a CDN from AWS. Thus the bucket name could be anything (randomstring).

You can restrict access to the bucket, such that only CloudFront can access it. Data in the bucket is then replicated to edge locations and served from there. Even if one knows the S3 URL, it will not do anything as access to the s3 bucket is restricted, an IAM rule grants CloudFront access and no one else.

Access restriction is done via origin access and while you can manually configure this using a bucket policy, you can also set a flag in CloudFront to do this on your behalf. More information is available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html).

Use the CloudFront name in Route53. Do not use CNAME, but rather use A type, and set it up as an Alias. For more information see this [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-cloudfront-distribution.html).

If you are using a different DNS provider, AWS aliases will naturally not be available. I suggest moving the zone file from your other provider to AWS. If you cannot do this, then you can still use a CNAME. Again see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html) for more information.

I suggest using your own domain name for CloudFront and setting up HTTPS. AWS offers certificates at no additional cost for services within AWS. You can register a certificate for your domain name which is either validated by a DNS entry or an Email. To set this up please see this [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-alternate-domain-names.html).

If you want to restrict access to specific files within AWS, you can use signed URLs. More information about that is provided [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html).